# Pandas query time range - update values inside query

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
   start_time_1    end_time_1    start_time_2    end_time_2
1 
2
```

I'm trying to filter the df on rows where:

```
df.query(
    "(start_time_1 <= start_time_2 <= end_time_1) or "
    "(start_time_2 <= start_time_1 <= end_time_2)"
)
```

This query works well but when I try to expand the time range by 10 seconds I have difficulties. This is what I've tried and it doest work:

```
df.query(
    "(start_time_1-timedelta(seconds=10) <= start_time_2 <= end_time_1+timedelta(seconds=10)) or "
    "(start_time_2-timedelta(seconds=10) <= start_time_1 <= end_time_2+timedelta(seconds=10))"
)
```

Any suggestions on how to execute this query?

Comment: What means `it doest work` ? Cn you add some sample data to question?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pd.Timedelta  and filter by loc function:

```
newdf = df.loc[(df['start_time_1'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)) < df['start_time_2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an external variable:

```
from datetime import timedelta

t = timedelta(seconds=10)

df.query(
    "(start_time_1-@t <= start_time_2 <= end_time_1+@t) or "
    "(start_time_2-@t <= start_time_1 <= end_time_2+@t)"
)
```